# a method that changes the result of a setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am assigned to write some ruby code that will work with the following (segment of a) rspec test:

```
before do
  @book = Book.new
end

describe 'title' do
  it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
    @book.title = "inferno"
    @book.title.should == "Inferno"
  end
```

This is the solution, but I don't understand it:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(new_title)
    words = new_title.split(" ")
    words = [words[0].capitalize] +
      words[1..-1].map do |word|
        little_words = %w{a an and the in of}
        if little_words.include? word
          word
        else
          word.capitalize
        end
      end
    @title = words.join(" ")
  end

end
```

I think I am correct to deduce that `@book.title = "inferno"` will run the `title` method and eventually create a new value for the `@title` variable at the bottom. I know that this causes `@book.title` to update to "Inferno" (capitalized), but I'm not sure why. Is this a case of `def title` being some sort of variable method, and `@title` being it's final value? That's my best guess at this point.

EDIT in case it's not clear, what I'm not understanding is why setting `@book.title ='inferno'` causes `@book.title` to update to "Inferno".

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.. What made you confused in this code?

Comment: @arup-rakshit declaring `@book.title ='inferno'` causes `@book.title` to update to "Inferno", but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have setter and getter methods in Ruby:

```
attr_writer :something
attr_reader :something
```

From my little understanding of this, these methods are equivalent to

```
def something=(value)
  @something = value
end

def something
  @something
end
```

Respectively.

Or in one statement, it could be:

```
attr_accessor :something
```

Anyway, what you are doing is to write the setter method yourself, capitalising each word of the string passed as an argument.

Comment: thank you. It was hard for me to understand that last part, that one could essentially update the setter code to include method code.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is almost correct. Here is a simple example

```
 class Chapter
   attr_reader :title
   def title=(new_title)
     @title = new_title.reverse
   end
 end

 @c = Chapter.new
 @c.title = "ybuR"
 @c.title #=> Ruby
```